# Multi-label Text class

Tags: classification, text-mining, multilabel

The data i am dealing with are simple text sentences that needs to be classified into variaous labels that correspond to the different topics as simple as Yes/No class. Several labels can be assigned to each sentences, hence multi-label classification task.

To solve a multilabel text classification problem I used tf-idf for feature engineering and calibrated+linearSVC into the model.

Results are great with 90+ accuracy for more labels, however, I am trying to figure out

1. **Why did one of the labels performed worse than others?**
2. **The missed classification data and analyze them as to why they have missed classification.**
3. **I am trying to analyze in the cases where the classifications was accurate, why are the probabilities low?**

So far I have taken the tf-tdf weights, features, the ouput of the model as predictions, probabilities, I understand how linearsvc works but I am unable to tie the weights to the predictions (Yes's and No's) and the probabilities assigned.

Please recommended an article or offer suggestions of how to go about resolving the above 3 queries.

Comment: @Carl, thank you so much for editing the content.